# Calculations with strings of numbers which are times (HH:MM:SS)

Tags: php, string

I was wondering if it is possible in PHP/Codeigniter to subtract values which are in a time format of

> HH:MM:SS

For example:

```
$time1 = "12:45:03";
$time2 = "14:03:48";

$timelength = $time2- $time1;
```

Any suggestions or link to code samples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this would be like

```php
//function to convert seconds into hour:minute:second
function sec2hms ($sec, $padHours = false) 
{

    // start with a blank string
    $hms = "";

     // do the hours first: there are 3600 seconds in an hour, so if we divide
     // the total number of seconds by 3600 and throw away the remainder, we're
     // left with the number of hours in those seconds
     $hours = intval(intval($sec) / 3600); 

     // add hours to $hms (with a leading 0 if asked for)
     $hms .= ($padHours) 
     ? str_pad($hours, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT). ":"
     : $hours. ":";

     // dividing the total seconds by 60 will give us the number of minutes
     // in total, but we're interested in *minutes past the hour* and to get
     // this, we have to divide by 60 again and then use the remainder
     $minutes = intval(($sec / 60) % 60); 

     // add minutes to $hms (with a leading 0 if needed)
     $hms .= str_pad($minutes, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT). ":";

    // seconds past the minute are found by dividing the total number of seconds
    // by 60 and using the remainder
    $seconds = intval($sec % 60); 

    // add seconds to $hms (with a leading 0 if needed)
    $hms .= str_pad($seconds, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

   // done!
   return $hms;

 }

$subtracted_time = strtotime($time2) - strtotime($time1); //gives difference in seconds
echo(sec2hms($subtracted_time));
```

function sec2hms source http://www.laughing-buddha.net/php/lib/sec2hms/

Comment: With this code, using the values provided in the question, `$subtracted_time` will have `10:12:45` as result, which does not correspond to the time difference! If we run the first line only, we will have the correct value, in seconds.

Comment: `m` in `date` function is for MONTH. `i` should be used for minutes. Anyway, `date` should not be used in this case. It considers you computer time locale settings - results will be different depending on the system.

Comment: I was very careless posting the answer. now this is a tested code.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `strtotime()` function to convert the times to UNIX time values. Then, you can subtract the two values because they'll be integers and then use the `date()` function to format the difference in the way you want.

Comment: `date()` function expects a timestamp parameter, i.e., "time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)" and is not appropriated for this. It considers the time locale. In my machine, `echo date('H:i:s', 0);` outputs `21:00:00` because my locale is GMT - 3.

Answer (score 2):

This is my suggestion (working PHP code):

```
$time1 = '12:45:03';
$time2 = '14:03:48';
$timelength = strtotime( $time2 ) - strtotime( $time1 );

$hours = intval( $timelength / 3600 );
$minutes = intval( ( $timelength % 3600 ) / 60 );
$seconds = $timelength % 60;

echo str_pad( $hours, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT ) . ':' . str_pad( $minutes, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT ) . ':' . str_pad( $seconds, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );
```

Output:

> 01:18:45

Answer (score 1):

use the following that will help you

```
function calculate_time_past($start_time, $end_time, $format = "s") { 
        $time_span = strtotime($end_time) - strtotime($start_time); 
        if ($format == "s") 
        { // is default format so dynamically calculate date format 
            if ($time_span > 60) { $format = "i:s"; } 
            if ($time_span > 3600) { $format = "H:i:s"; } 
        } 
        return gmdate($format, $time_span); 
} 

$tdiff=calculate_time_past($time1, $time2, "H:i:s"); // will output 00:02:45 when format is overridden
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to BenGC's answer

```
$tmp_time1 = strtotime($submit_date);
$tmp_time2 = strtotime($submit_date);
$timelength = $tmp_time2 - $tmp_time1;
```

Should work, I haven't tested it, but I have used code very similar. You get the number of seconds between the two times.